# Svn-log '.' Svn is not a working copy

Tags: svn, logging

In the command prompt i typed svn log or any svn command in the command prompt it gives the same answer like  svn: '.' is not a working copy. but in the svn --version command is working properly. the svn version is 1.6.6..

Please give me the answer.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to either:

1. run `svn log` in a directory that has been checked out from a Subversion repository (as in the other answers)
2. run `svn log` against the URL of a remote or local repository, e.g.

   ```
   svn log -l 1 http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk
   ```
3. if you're trying to run `svn log` against your own repository then you can't just run it from the repos directory; you'd need to run it against a file URL for that directory e.g.

   ```
   svn log -l 1 file:///my/repository/path
   ```

   if you repository is in /my/repository/path, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`svn log` works with you project checked out from repository with svn

and `svn --version` will give the version of svn installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute that command in a directory that has a ".svn" folder in it with the contents needed by svn. This is present, when you checked out a folder from the repository using the `co` command.